# What does RegGetValue return when the requested registry value is not found?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Suppose you want to develop a function that, given a valid registry key handle and a value name, returns *true* if the value exists under the input key, *false* if it doesn't, and throws a C++ exception in all other cases.

```
bool RegValueExists(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring& value)
{
    LRESULT retCode = ::RegGetValue(
        hKey, 
        nullptr,                   // no subkey 
        value.c_str(), 
        RRF_RT_ANY,                // any type
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr  // not interested in these
    );
```

If `RegGetValue` succeeds, it returns `0`; so, in this case I can return `true` to the caller.

But, from [the MSDN documentation of `RegGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx), it's *not* clear what the API returns in case of registry value not found:

> **Return value**
>
> [...]  If the function fails, the return value is a system error code.

In my tests, `RegGetValue` returns `2` (i.e. **`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`**) in case of values not found. However, I cannot find any *official* MSDN page documenting that. (Moreover, since when is a registry value a *file*??)

Among the *"system error codes"* there's also an `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` code (`1168`). Would it be reasonable to expect it as a return code for *"registry value not found"*?

I think there should be a clear explanation of at least the *common* error codes in MSDN.

Comment: You are asking for exception specifications.  Can't get them from C++, can't get them from the winapi.  *Anything* can go wrong, the underlying file system driver is not necessarily Microsoft's.  Looking at .NET Framework source code is a pretty decent way to find out what they considered a decent mapping.  That sometimes still goes wrong, but not very often, it was tested pretty well.

Comment: I'm not asking of documenting all possible failure modes, but most common ones (as already written in my question). And the case of a registry value not found is a common case and the return code for it should be clearly documented. Moreover, it's not clear why the -1 downvote.

Comment: From the kernel's perspective, a registry value is much the same as a file, they're all just objects in the kernel namespace.  You can expect to see `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for pretty much anything that can be referenced by name, e.g., synchronization objects, devices, desktops, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no documentation of all the failure modes and their error codes. That's just the way of things. Certain failure modes are explicitly called out with the error code documented.

However, I can confirm that `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is the error code associated with the failure mode described in the question.

Comment: As already written in my question, I'm not asking of documenting _all_ the possible failure modes, but the most _common_ ones, and I believe the one I asked should be included, just like they documented `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. However, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

[`RegQueryValueEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) has a more detailed error specification:

> If the lpValueName registry value does not exist, the function returns
>   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

So if you want to be on the safe side, use that function instead of `RegGetValue`.

From your example I see that you don't need any of the special features of `RegGetValue` and I think these features could even be emulated with a combination of [`RegOpenKeyEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`RegQueryValueEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for pointing RegQueryValueEx's doc. The fact that this error code is documented in this API but not in RegGetValue makes me think of a doc bug/omission in the RegGetValue MSDN page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be reasonable to expect any returned value but ERROR_SUCCESS to be an error code. The exact list of potentially returned error codes probably varies between Windows versions.

> I think there should be a clear explanation of at least the common error codes in MSDN.

But your quote from MSDN page actually contains a link to the [list of system error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx), you can also get an error description at any time by calling `FormatMessageW`.